# When would you use Storyboard vs Nib/Xib vs Coding from scratch?

Tags: ios

what are the pro's and con's of each, and what would be the proper way to responde to a question like this in an interview :

When would you use Storyboard vs Nib/Xib vs Coding from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very objective question to answer. But I will give you my take on it. When I am creating basic UI navigation which is also using the stock UI controls then I use Storyboards.

There are certain scenarios where I am either using a third party component or I am developing a user control from scratch. In those cases I use coding from scratch. If you are coding from scratch then you can also utilize and control the look and feel of the different UI components much easily. Of course you can also do that from Storyboards by inheriting from the TitleLabel instead of UILabel but that approach is quite restrictive.

Unfortunately, there is hard and fast rule of choosing one or the other. It all depends on the situation.

Comment: There seem to be a few key typos in this answer. The question is subjective, not objective. And the last sentence should say "there is **no** hard and fast rule".

Comment: Thanks for the response, appreciate it